# Adobe Acrobat Action Wizard JavaScript. Create TextFiled and update TextField With current Date?

Tags: javascript, macros, adobe, acrobat

I am using the action wizard to perform some highlighting on bulk PDF documents. I would also like to add a DATE STAMP to the PDF file for the day it was processed (date Action Wizard Runs), and I think I am very close.

I can create the text field needed, but I am having problems updated to the text field the current date via the JavaScript code I have in action wizard. Why does this create the field, but does not add the date to it?

```
var fld = this.getField("MacroDate");
if ( fld==null ) {
    var f = this.addField("info", "text", 0, [11,11, 61,26]);
    f.delay = true;
    f.alignment = "center";
    f.fillColor = color.white;
    f.lineWidth = 1;
    f.strokeColor = color.black;
    f.borderStyle = style.s;
    f.textSize = 14;
    f.textColor = color.black;
    f.textFont = font.Arial;
    f.defaultValue = "MacroDate";
    f.editable = false;
    f.multiline = false;
    f.doNotScroll = true;
    f.delay = false;
    var TodayDate = this.getField("MacroDate");
    TodayDate.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new date());
}
```

After doing some more digging I did manage to get it to work:

I am not exactly sure why it worked, but here is the code if anyone wants to explain it:

```
var AcDate = new Date();
var AcDateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++){

    var fd = this.addField("xftDate", "text", 0, [10, 10, 100, 25]);
    fd.value =  util.printd(AcDateFormat, AcDate);
    fd.textSize = 16;
    fd.readonly = true;
    fd.alignment = "right";
}
flattenPages();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by a quick glance, the issue is in the last line:

```
TodayDate.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new date());
```

In JavaScript, Capitalization does matter. And the Date Object is capitalized. Therefore:

```
TodayDate.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new Date()) ;
```

You also should activate the Console, where you will get messages if errors occur.

Comment: I am not sure how to activate a console from within adobe acrobat pro. Also The capitalization of Date did not help.

Comment: I have figured out how to get into adobe acrobats console. I am troubleshooting now. I will mess with it for a bit before I update my question to include the error if I can not figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. I looked up how to open the console in acrobat. That help. I did not know there was a console to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a variable to represent the field so you can just set the value using it. You can simplify it a bit by using the following.

```
var fld = this.getField("MacroDate");
if ( fld = "undefined" ) {
    var f = this.addField("MacroDate", "text", 0, [11,11, (72*1.5)+11,26]);
    f.delay = true;
    f.alignment = "center";
    f.fillColor = color.white;
    f.lineWidth = 1;
    f.strokeColor = color.black;
    f.borderStyle = border.s;
    f.textSize = 14;
    f.textColor = color.black;
    f.textFont = font.Helv;
    f.readonly = false;
    f.multiline = false;
    f.doNotScroll = true;
    f.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new Date());
    f.delay = false;
}
```

Comment: I actually started out with something like this. It was giving me the same problem. That is why I was playing with other options. It does create the field on the pdf file but it never updates the field with the current date. Or anything for that matter.

Comment: I updated my answer with more code corrections. There were a bunch of problems with the properties. I also expanded the rect to fit the content once I actually got it working.

Comment: I did actually fix the problem I was having. The issue was more related to the font I was trying to use. For some reason it really didn't like the font. I have added an edit section in my question to show what I did to resolve my problem.

Comment: Yeah - the font was one of the properties I fixed in my answer. Glad it's working now.